# Преобразование двузначного строчного числа в integer

Tags: python, python-3.x, строки, список, числа

Появилась необходимость получения из строки типа `("2 4 7 8 10")` получить все числа ОТДЕЛЬНО и целиком в отдельный список и все бы ничего, если бы не десятка в конце. Я никак не могу придумать, как и ее тоже впихнуть в список, не перегружая код еще десятком строк. Получается только разбивать ее на 1 и 0, что меня не устраивает. Можно и соединить, конечно, но я же пишу максимально гибкий код, а это - костыль. Как максимально коротко и понятно можно перенести все числа в отдельный целочисленный список, чтобы к ним можно было позже обратиться по отдельности?

Comment: `list(map(int, "2 4 7 8 10".split(' ')))`

Comment: Всем спасибо за помощь в решении. Обязательно запомню решение)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Можно разбить строку по пробелам, используя функцию [`split`](https://docs.python.org/3.3/library/stdtypes.html?highlight=split#str.split). После чего преобразовать строки в числа с помощью [`map`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#map).

***Пример:***

```py
s = "2 4 7 8 10"

nums = list(map(int, s.split()))
print(nums)
```

***stdout:***

```py
[2, 4, 7, 8, 10]
```